# Обращение к TextView внутри фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-textview

Я хочу "засетерить" в TextView внутри  динамического фрагмента какой-нибудь текст
Как это лучше сделать?
Код фрагмента

```
public class RussianFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;



    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public RussianFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment RussianFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static RussianFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        RussianFragment fragment = new RussianFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_russian,container,false);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        TextView WordR = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.WordRussian);
        WordR.setText("ghhfh");

        return v;
    }
```

В таком случае при переходе на фрагмент, приложение вылетает. Это связано с textView WordR. Как лучше обращаться к textView внутри фрагмента и с чем может быть связан вылет из приложения при переходе на этот фрагмент?

Comment: Просто getActicity замените на v , это есть ваша view фрагмента которой вы раздуваете его

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно обратиться к виджету из макета самого фрагмента, то искать его нужно не в активности, а во вью-контейнере, созданном в `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_russian,container,false);
    //   ^
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    TextView WordR = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.WordRussian);
    //                          ^
    WordR.setText("ghhfh");

    return v;
}
```

Если нужно будет обращаться к нему за пределами метода, то ,соответственно, нужно сделать его полем класса фрагмента.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, обращаться напрямую из фрагмента к элементам активити, не совсем хорошая идея. Хоть и можно получать экземпляр активити из фрагмента методом `getActivity()`, этот метод не гарантирует, что мы получим его, есть вероятность что метод вернет `null`. Можно конечно попробовать получить элемент из активити в других событиях фрагмента, например `onViewCreated` или `onStart`, но все же это не совсем правильно.

Что рекомендуется: стандартное из мануалов и самое простое передавать данные в активити по callback-функции, то есть определить интерфейс с функцией обратного вызова, например

```
interface OnActivityTextViewCallback{
  void setText(String s);
}
```

Реализовать этот интерфейс в активити, во фрагменте создать поле `OnActivityTextViewCallback onActivityTextViewCallback`, туда передавать активти, реализующий этот самый интерфейс и общаться с активити по интерфейсу, то есть дергать уже методы интерфейса, а там уже само активити должно само решать, что делать с данными, пришедшими из фрагмента.

Замечу, что это не единственный вариант решения.

Comment: Автор же просто хочет показать аргументы в фрагменте , ему не требуется их взаимодействие. Да и кстати вы хоть раз видел чтоб фрагменты жили без Activity, конечно с абстракциями работать лучше, но вашем ответе есть доля заблуждения. Ваше решение не обезопасит вас от расхождения жз, в Kotlin это выглядит гораздо лаконичнее

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, да, я не внимательно прочитал вопрос... ему и не требуется элемент из активити. А по поводу ЖЦ, возможно и ошибся, поглубже постараюсь изучить вопрос, спасибо.